# How do I add a tab Index for dynamically created elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help in adding a `tabindex` to all the elements in a `<div>` dynamically. I need to do this for accessibility. If I specify a `<div>` element, it should automatically add the `tabindex` to all elements in that `<div>`.

I tried some thing like this:

```
$('#Latest-News-Content [tabindex]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr( 'tabindex', parseInt( $(this).attr('tabindex') ) + 10 )
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Also, how can I add a tab index for elements which are hidden?

For example:

I have a title and description showing in a `<div>`. The description is hidden and has a `jQuery collapser`. When I click on the title the description expands. How can I set a `tabindex` for all the elements?

Answer (score 8):

Here an example that adds `tabindex` for all `a` tags

```
$('#Latest-News-Content a').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', index)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/azk2n/1

You can use the same method for hidden elements.

Comment: +1: great solution. I suggested a small change: `index+1` instead of `index` behaved closer to what I wanted in Safari.

Comment: This will not trigger automatically upon new dynamic data showing up in the DOM. This will only add the tabindex attribute to the  matching existing DOM elements at the moment this code is executed. You can either re-run this each time something new shows up, or better yet, watch the `body` and `find` your elements from there.

Answer (score 5):

@Sotiris

This might be an update with newer versions of jQuery. Use .prop() instead of .attr() to set property values.

```
$('#Latest-News-Content a').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prop('tabindex', index)
});
```